# How to call the PIM Graph API endpoints?

Tags: powershell, microsoft-graph-api

I am trying to call the PIM (Privileged Identity Management) REST endpoints via the Graph API using PowerShell.
In Graph Explorer I try `https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/policies/roleManagementPolicies` but it returns `"{\"errorCode\":\"MissingProvider\",\"message\":\"The provider is missing.\",\"instanceAnnotations\":[]}"`

I have gone down a rabbit hole with the MS documentation on this. Closest I got was they suggested the Powershell SDK, which is the new Microsoft.graph module. The equivalent cmdlet is `Get-MgPolicyRoleManagementPolicy` which returns a similar error `{"errorCode":"MissingProvider","message":"The provider is missing.","instanceAnnotations":[]}`.
I can't find anywhere how to supply it the missing information. I know this is beta and pretty bleeding edge, but I'm hoping someone has been down this and found a solution. There's an outstanding issue on GitHub for this, but the author/owner is conspicuously absent

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is know issue - https://github.com/microsoftgraph/microsoft-graph-docs/issues/15910?msclkid=c0822b1ca5cf11ec93ebea64a421b423

we will try to escalate this with dev team

[image]

Comment: This has been discussed (finalky!) in more detail in that GH issues thread, so I'm going to mark this as correct (although I was participating in that discussion before I came here)

Answer (score 0):

The below query will help fix the issue.

[https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/policies/roleManagementPolicies?$filter=scopeId+eq+'/'+and+scopeType+eq+'DirectoryRole'](https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/policies/roleManagementPolicies?$filter=scopeId+eq+%27/%27+and+scopeType+eq+%27DirectoryRole%27)

The scopeId and scopeType are required in the URL, will raise a PR to fix the docs.